# Using "so that" instead of "ensure"

Tags: grammaticality

I am reviewing a set of guidelines which make frequent use of *to ensure*, like:

> The soup should be taken off the gas after cooking, **to ensure** that it does not burn.

I want the text to be less clumsy, so I’d like to change *to ensure* to *so that*, like:

> The soup should be taken off the gas after cooking, **so that** it does not burn.

Is the latter correct?

Comment: Yeah, technically, but you'd have to be a pretty lousy cook to burn soup. Maybe, "Remove the soup from the heat after cooking, so the vegetables don't become mushy"  or "it doesn't over-thicken" or something like that.

Comment: @Oldbag Maybe I am a pretty lousy cook, but I managed to royally burn the living daylights (if soup has any) out of a root vegetable soup a couple of weeks ago. It’s not that difficult.

Comment: @Oldbag Soups with a cream base can burn fairly easily.

Comment: I would say "When the soup is fully cooked, take it off the stove top [or gas] to prevent it from burning."

Answer (score 1):

"So that..." Is a statement which implicitly leads to a following sequential step in a process.

It may be that the next step is positive, negative or neutral.  However it tells the reader that the preceding statement absolutely forms part of a larger whole.

The word "ensure" is not necessarily a sequential step.  It means guarantee, to guarantee or to provide certainty.  I would use ensure when you wish to place emphasis on a **critical** action rather than to explain the potential consequences of a sequential step being mis-performed.

Comment: I don't notice this distinction in his example sentences. Can you give examples of each where you can't substitute the other?

Comment: The following sentence "You are required to ensure that the keys are locked in the cabinet."

Comment: _so that_ wouldn't even be grammatical in that sentence. Can you give examples that use the phrases in the same manner as he's using, where you couldn't swap them? IMHO, both his sentences are fine.

Comment: I never said they are not fine.  I am explaining to the OP the finer point of their use.  It is not a binary issue.   However the sentence "Take the soup off the hob so that it does not burn" is a sequential result.  The sentence "Take the soup off the hob to ensure that it does not burn" is not sequential.  It is merely instructing the cook to make certain the soup is not burned.  The preceding part of the sentence saying "take the soup off the hob" is redundant.  The sentence can read "Ensure the soup does not burn".  That is a complete instruction.

Comment: However "So that..." is not a complete instruction since it requires either a post or pre qualification.

Comment: You seem to be ignoring _to_, which is short for _in order to_. That provides the causal link between taking the soup off the gas and ensuring that it doesn't burn.

Comment: The example you gave in your comment is using _to_ to mark an infinitive, not as part of the abbreviated _in order to_.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the latter is correct, though I don't think it sounds any less formal/clumsy than your use of "ensure".

How about: "To avoid burning, the soup should be taken off the gas after cooking"?

Or: "After cooking, take the soup off the gas, to avoid burning it"?

Or: "After cooking, take the soup off the gas, so as not to burn it"?

Comment: I'd put "it" after burning in your first suggested sentence.  As it stands, it might be the cook rather than  the soup that's in danger of burning.

Comment: If the purpose is to sound informal, the second clause could be a simple, "so it doesn't burn."